# JAVA: FileInputStream and FileOutputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have this strange thing with input and output streams, whitch I just can't understand.
I use inputstream to read properties file from resources like this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/resources/SQL.properties" );
rop.load(in);
return prop;
```

It finds my file and reds it succesfully. I try to write modificated settings like this:

```
prop.store(new FileOutputStream( "/resources/SQL.properties" ), null);
```

And I getting strange error from storing:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \resources\SQL.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

So why path to properties are changed? How to fix this?
I am using Netbeans on Windows

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for a well-phrased question with all the appropriate information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be it works

```
try
{
java.net.URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/SQL.properties");

java.io.FileInputStream pin = new java.io.FileInputStream(url.getFile());

java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();

props.load(pin);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

and check the below url

[getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `getResourceAsStream()` is resolving the path you give it relative to the classpath, while `new FileOutputStream()` creates the file directly in the filesystem.  They have different starting points for the path.

In general you cannot write back to the source location from which a resource was loaded, as it may not exist in the filesystem at all.  It may be in a jar file, for instance, and the JVM will not update the jar file.

Comment: May you gime me an a example how to write it corectly?

Comment: You cannot write it correctly.  You cannot in general write to the location from which a resource was loaded.  It may not exist in a writable location.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this question: [How can I save a file to the class path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4714645/239168)

And this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714719/239168

In summary: you can't always trivially save back a file your read from the classpath (e.g. a file in a 
jar)

However if it was indeed just a file on the classpath, the above answer has a nice approach