# Writing to a properties file does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, file, properties

I want to write into a *.properties file. Thats my code how I do this:

```
    properties = loadProperties("user.properties");//loads the properties file
    properties.setProperty(username, password);
        try {
                properties.store(new FileOutputStream("user.properties"), null);
                System.out.println("Wrote to propteries file!" + username + " " + password);
```

I do not get an exception, but I also do not get the output written into the file.

Here is also my file-structure:

[image]

I appreciate your answer!!!

**UPDATE**

I load my properties file with:

```
    InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename);
```

My question is, how to load it from a specific path?

Here is my "new" File Structure:

[image]

Comment: I have tested your code and my properties file is created in my working directory. Of course, with your file structure that is wrong. I guess that you must use a path to your file instead of just using the file name

Comment: when I use the path like \\user.properties I get "You have no rights to access the file..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my testing code:

```
@Test
public void fileTest() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File file = null;

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("Hello", "World");

    URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResource("exceptions/user.properties");

    try {
        file = new File(url.toURI().getPath());

        assertTrue(file.exists());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    props.store(new FileOutputStream(file), "OMG, It werks!");

}
```

It does creates and rewrites a file in my target/classes/exceptions directory (in a maven/eclipse proyect) so I guess it really works, but of course that is not tested in a JAR file.

Here is the file:

```
#OMG, It werks!
#Sat Nov 10 08:32:44 CST 2012
Hello=World
```

Also, check this question: [How can i save a file to the class path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714645/how-can-i-save-a-file-to-the-class-path)

So maybe what you want to do never will work.

Comment: I am printint he URL for checking and it is giving me as

:/C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/workspace/A_Migration_final/bin/common/props_1.dat

but the correct URL is
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\workspace\A_Migration_final\src\common\props.dat
It's writing in the bin file, do you think it would give the correct values when queried ?